# Create a const array with values at certain indices

Tags: dart

I need to provide a `const` array to a property in my class. I need certain indices to have a value in the array. How would I create such an array ... it's important that the array is a `const` because I'm assigning a value to a non null property in my class.

Comment: A const list can be created as `const [constValue1, constValue2, ..., constValueN]`.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning to non-nullable properties is possible (once) at run time if you mark them with the `late` keyword. Optionally, your property may be `final`, too.

```
class C {
  late final List<int> myList;

  C() {
    myList = [1, 2, 4];
}
```

You could also use an [unmodifiable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/List.unmodifiable.html) list.